# Deploying multiple Python applications on the same Compute Engine server / Docker

Tags: python, gunicorn

I am a PHP developer(10 years) currently learning Python(2 months).

I currently have a server on Compute Engine with about 10 domains hosted with 10 different websites/applications.
Each application has requirements such as SSL, caching, database connectivity etc.

I am building a few Python (Django and Flask) applications and I stuck on deploying them. When I run the Django application using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

the terminal is occupied and I cannot launch another application on a different port. The same issue for Gunicorn.

Each Python application will have a database connection, SSL, Cache etc.

With my PHP application, I use Nginx to point to the folder, LetsEncrypt to add SSL to the site and I can deploy the applications on the same server using different folders for each application. I can also re-start the server from the Compute Engine admin(which I need to do) and once the server starts, all websites are available to the end users.

I would like to understand how to do the same with Python. As these projects are not being paid for/bringing in revenue I cannot host them on their own servers due to cost.

I use Docker containers for development on my computer so I understand that I can deploy each application on a separate container. I do not want to take this route.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. runserver is not for production use anyway; but when using gunicorn why wouldn't you run them on different ports? Especially if you're using nginx as a reverse proxy, it doesn't matter what port the gunicorn app is running on.

Comment: When I start an application using Gunicorn, `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 wsgi &` the terminal is occupied and shows that the service is running.. `Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80` , how do I start another application on the same server?

Comment: Like I said, don't run any of them on port 80. Gunicorn is not supposed to be exposed externally anyway; use nginx as the reverse proxy.

Comment: (Although I must also say, you are seriously missing the point of Docker if you're running multiple applications in the same container.)

Comment: It's about the cost factor. A simple LAMP docker container takes about 200MB of Ram. I have about 10 applications (Actually 20) running on the server. 10 * 200 MB = ~2GB. The cost for that is approximately $24.67 per month which is not feasible for projects that  I work on. Docker is great at containing the whole application. I like it and would like to use it some day for critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

If gunicorn isn't your hard requirement, you can try **uWSGI** with it's [Emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html) mode.

In simple words: **Emperor** monitors some sources (i.e., directory), and is looking for **Vassals** (your applications) config files, to run them and manage. So, with a small effort, you can create a configuration to run your all applications with a single process (that will spawn another process in the background but as I understand that's not an issue).

But, you should consider deploying these applications in different containers, as this approach is missing the point of containerization.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this approach.